# mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found during UPDATE

Tags: python, mysql

Here is my code:

```
postconn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='Infinity8', host='127.0.0.1', database='geodb')
postcursor = postconn.cursor() # creating cursor
....
print ("currently selected ID: ", mydata[0])
sql_update_flag = """ UPDATE REQUESTS SET fl_ready = {0} WHERE request_id={1} """.format(set_flag, current_id)
print (sql_update_flag)
print ("Before commit")
currSrc.execute(sql_update_flag)
print "after commit"
connSrc.commit()
```

After execution it's fail with next log:

`('currently selected ID: ', 10)
 UPDATE REQUESTS SET fl_ready = 11 WHERE request_id=10
Before commit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\monitoring\GetRequest.py", line 168, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\monitoring\GetRequest.py", line 164, in main
    SyncRequest(postconn, fireconn)
  File "C:\monitoring\GetRequest.py", line 92, in SyncRequest
    currSrc.execute(sql_update_flag)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 485, in execute
    self._connection.handle_unread_result()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1057, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found`

It's seems that problem is here:
`currSrc.execute(sql_update_flag)`

But what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try with buffer: `postcursor = postconn.cursor(buffered=True)`

Comment: Do not helped. Same result :(

Comment: Are you sure this cursor is not used anywhere else at the same time or has some unread data inside? Try reading everything from the cursor before using your update statement.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to fetch all rows before performing any other operations.**

You can do this:

```
...
# do SELECT
postcursor.execute("SELECT ...")
rows = postcursor.fetchall()
...
# do UPDATE
```